# pygal ImportError with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pygal

I'm sure I've done something stupid and the answer is simple, but I can't find it... I want to use pygal on GAE, so I have copied the whole *pygal* directory to my *lib* directory. Then, I import it (from another file in *lib*):

```
import pygal
```

Now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>

    from lib import output_lib

  File "lib\output_lib.py", line 14, in <module>

    import pygal

  File "lib\pygal\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>

    from pygal.graph.bar import Bar

ImportError: No module named pygal.graph.bar
```

I can fix this by changing

```
from pygal.graph.bar import Bar
```

in *pygal/__init__.py* to

```
from graph.bar import Bar
```

but this leads to the next iteration of the error:

```
 ...

 File "lib\pygal\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>

   from graph.bar import Bar

 File "lib\pygal\graph\bar.py", line 27, in <module>

   from pygal.graph.graph import Graph

ImportError: No module named pygal.graph.graph
```

So - what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

For want of a better solution, I replaced all occurrences of `from pygal.*` to `from lib.pygal.*` in all files' import statements. It works, though I still think there must be another way...